# How to have (at the same time) multiple redirectSignIn / redirectSignOut with amplify auth in Angular app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I am using `@aws-amplify/auth@6.0.3` and `@aws-amplify/ui-angular@5.0.1`

My target is having both domain `http://localhost:4200` (Angular dev server) and `https://abc.cloudfront.net` (my site hosted in CloudFront) in the `redirectSignIn / redirectSignOut`.

I could have each domain separately and both worked (in order to have the other, I must delete the amplify app and redo all the integration steps again: `amplify delete`, `amplify init`, `amplify add auth`, `amplify push`).

I've tried other possibilities which I could imagine but all of them didn't work:

- Add a second environment: did not work because the command `amplify env add <env-name>` does not ask to input `redirectSignIn / redirectSignOut` at all.
- Directly modify `redirectSignIn / redirectSignOut` in `amplifyconfiguration.json` according to the information here: https://docs.amplify.aws/angular/build-a-backend/auth/add-social-provider/#redirect-urls except in my used amplify javascript package version the json object looks a bit different but it seemed I could manage to input the URLs right. But only the one  domain that was input during "amplify add auth" worked, the one that was added later through modifying `amplifyconfiguration.json` did not work. In this attempt, I also manually updated Cognito app client hosted UI allowed callback URLs accordingly because `amplify push` actually didn't perform any update in the cloud after the modifying of `amplifyconfiguration.json`.
- Input URLs of all the needed domains during `amplify add auth`. This could perform best of all the attempts. Sign-in worked for both domains. But the sign-out flow didn't start anymore. Visiting the `<amplify-authenticator><ng-template>` after signed in just brought up the sign-in form again, not the sign-out form.

Could anyone give me a hint what should I do to achieve the target?
I don't know if the info plays some role here: I use login with Facebook and Google in my app.